# Why does the image not show up whilst implementing Bootstrap for Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-4

I am trying to implement bootstrap to my ruby application but failing to understand why the image is not displaying.

I am trying to implement this bootstrap. https://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-clean-blog/.

The image is stored in Assets/Images

**index.html.erb:**

```
<!-- Page Header -->
<header class="masthead" <img class="img-responsive img-full" src="../assets/home-bg.jpg" alt="">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-10 mx-auto">
      <div class="site-heading">
        <h1>Start Bootstrap</h1>
        <span class="subheading">Technology made simple in a blink of an eye!</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Current layout of page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sdmKb.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is in the `app/assets/images/` folder then just use the image tag.

```
<%= image_tag 'home-bg.jpg' %>
```

If you do not want to do that for some reason, then just inspect that page to see where it is looking for the image and adjust the path accordingly.